# Python beautiful soup merging rows

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

here is the html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="break">mono</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c1</td>
<td>c2</td>
<td>c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c11</td>
<td>c22</td>
<td>c33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="break">dono</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>d1</td>
<td>d2</td>
<td>d3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>d11</td>
<td>d22</td>
<td>d33</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I want output like this in a csv file:

```
mono c1 c2 c3
mono c11 c22 c33
dono d1 d2 d3
dono d11 d22 d33
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
mono
c1 c2 c3
c11 c22 c33
dono
d1 d2 d3
d11 d22 d33
```

Here is my code:

```
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with codecs.open('dump.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:


    f = open("input.html","r")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    t = soup.findAll('table')
    for table in t:
        rows = table.findAll('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            cols = tr.findAll('td')
            for td in cols:
                csvfile.write(str(td.find(text=True)))
                csvfile.write(",")
            csvfile.write("\n")
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.Thanks.

Edit:

Explained with some more details.Here I need to add first  section (mono,dono etc) to be appended.

The rule here is that unless I encountered a new "break" class,text inside of that class should be appended to any tr below that.

Comment: What is the rule for when a row is really a new header, and when it's a continuation? When the column text is exactly 4 characters long? or has no digits? When there's only 1 column? Every 3rd row? All of these, and probably many other possibilities, are plausible inferences from your input data, but either all, or all but one, are not what you want. So you have to explicitly decide, and tell us, the rule for what you want.

Comment: ok.edited again.thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your new question is effectively an entirely different question from the original, here's an entirely different answer:

```
for table in t:
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        if 'break' in cols[0].get('class', []):
            header = cols[0].text
        else:
            print header, ' '.join(col.text for col in cols)
```

I'm assuming that a row will either be exactly 1 "break" column, or 1 or more regular columns. If those assumptions aren't true, the code can be modified.

Also, if the generator expression in the `join` function confuses you, the same thing can be rewritten as an explicit loop: print the header; then for each column, print that column; then print a newline.

Since you asked for an explanation of `'break' in cols[0].get('class', [])`, I'll break it down.

- `cols` is a `list` of the BS4 `Tag` objects for every `td` nodes in the current `tr` node.
- `cols[0]` is the first one.
- `cols[0].get('class', [])` treats the `Tag` object as a dictionary, as described in [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes), and calls the familiar `get(key, defaultvalue)` method on it.

  - In BS4 (unlike older versions), looking up `Tag` attributes by name always returns a `list`. While BS3 would return `'foo bar'` for `<td class='foo bar'>` and `'bar'` for `<td class='foo' class='bar'>`, BS4 will return `['foo', 'bar']` for both.
- Putting it all together, `cols[0].get('class', [])` will be `['break']` for the `<td class='break'>` case, and `[]` for all of the other cases in your sample input.

As mentioned above, I'm assuming that a row will either be exactly 1 "break" column, or 1 or more regular columns. You can see where I'm making use of those assumptions in the code. But if any of those assumptions are broken, you haven't told us enough to know what you want to do in those cases.

If you have any rows with no columns, obviously the `cols[0]` will raise an `IndexError`. But you have to decide what to do in that case. Should it do nothing? Print just the header? Change to a state where nothing gets printed until we see a header row? Whatever you decide, it should be easy to code.

If you have any rows with a header followed by normal rows, the normal rows will be ignored. If you have any headers that aren't the first column in a row, they will be treated like normal values. If you have multiple headers in the same row, all but the first will be ignored. And so on. In each case, this may or may not be what. But you have to decide what you want, before you can write the code.

Comment: if 'break' in cols[0].get('class', []): this line is giving IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you please tell me what cols[0].get('class', []):
is doing?

Comment: I'll add an explanation to the answer. And if it's failing on your real data set, please post your real data set somewhere—or, even better, strip it down to just enough to reproduce the problem, and post that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.Its not the fish,but now I know how to catch the fish.and yes I solved the problems related to my case and this code is fine.:)

Comment: @MBanerjee: Remember that answers here are supposed to help future searchers as well as the original asker. So, if there's an extra trick you need here that you figured out from my answer, that you think would help others, it might be worth updating the question and/or answer. But otherwise, glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `csv` module for working with CSV files. It's much easier than manually doing it.

As for your problem, this is happening because your `csvfile.write('\n')` is indented too far, so the data is written just like it appears in the table. Make a generator instead and it should work:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_fields(soup):
    for td in soup.find_all('td'):
        yield td.get_text().strip()

with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    with open('input.html', 'r') as handle:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(handle.read())

    fields = list(get_fields(soup))

    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'table' is not defined

Comment: @MBanerjee: Change `table` to `soup`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried un-indenting `csvfile.write("\n")` so that it occurs at the end of the table loop, not the tr loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run all the rows in the table together, why not just ignore the rows?

```
for table in t:
    cols = table.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        csvfile.write(str(td.find(text=True)))
        csvfile.write(",")
    csvfile.write("\n")
```

Half the reason to use BeautifulSoup instead of a strict parser is to let you play loose with the structure (the other half is to let you deal with people who played loose while generating the structure). So, why go row by row and then try to ignore the row-by-rowness when you can just go column by column?

You'd be much better off using the `csv` module than trying to format it manually, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @abarnert-"f you want to run all the rows in the table together"-but thats now what I want.please check the edited question.sorry for the confusion